# How do i export a dataframe to a csv without quotation marks?

Tags: python

I have an output dataframe which i want to get into a .out file (same thing as csv without commas), but when i do the list comes back with quotation marks. For example, 1 cell is `2.328e+00+ j 0.0000e+00`. When I look at it in the output file it looks like `"2.328e+00+ j 0.0000e+00"`. I tried using the following code:

```
Output.to_csv (r'C:\Users\[DIRECTORY OMITTED]\export_dataframe.out', sep=' ', index = False, header=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,escapechar=" ")
```

however the issue with this is that every space comes back double spaced. Using another escape character doesnt work as this populates all spaces with the escape character. Formatting is extremely important, so is there any way I can export the dataframe whilst retaining the formatting, without apostrophe marks?

Kind regards,

Tom_Ice

Comment: How should for this format a space in a cell be distinguished from a space separating cells?

Comment: Dont worry issue solved :)